# Ubuntu installation skips a step?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have just changed my HDD on my pc to 500gb one. Since my motherboard has only one SATA port, i had to remove the older one. Therefore, i installed Windows XP on it first. Then, i rebooted and then booted from my USB containing Ubuntu 13.04. I selected install Ubuntu. I went through the first step (the neccessary requirements one) and then it took me to a step showing me 3 partitions. Actually, one of them referred to the whole HDD, whereas the other two were partitions. One of them was Windows XP NTFS partition. The pther was Windows recovery partition.

I don't know why, it did not show me the step to select "Install alongside Windows". It took me to a step where i had option to select to either wipe the whole hdd, or "Something Else".
I counted the steps, it was 1, 2 and then suddenly 4! Whats up with this thing? Corrupted pen drive?

Although i can do one thing, which i think should work. I can use some partition tool on windows to create another partition, and then select that partition for ubuntu. But before doing that i want to know whether this problem can be solved without it or not. Because i know that GParted is a powerful tool, and that would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. My problem was a little different, so I had to use a 3rd Party tool, EASUS Partition manager. So I shrinked my Windows partition, and left the unallocated part like that.
The rest of the work, Ubuntu's installer did itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no unallocated space and/or do not have another primary partition to use as the extended partition the only options are to totally replace whatever you have or manually change partitions around.

You need to shrink the XP partition. Best to do that with gparted on live installer and then boot XP so it can run chkdsk and make its repairs. Then you will have unallocated and if you have not used all 4 primary partitions you can do the auto install or manually create partitions.

You can also create partitions while in gparted, but still have to use manual install to chose which is / (root) what format (ext4) and then if you want /home and its format. If swap exists it will auto find that. And if you have swap already, the install may be a bit quicker as it will use swap as part of the install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Install with separate /home

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome

Comment: That is the problem. I can't change the size or shrink Windows partition using GParted. The only option it gives me in "Something Else" looks like this:

/dev/sda
/dev/sda fat32 - Windows Recovery
/dev/sda NTFS - Windows XP Media Center Edition

Sorry, this forum is not letting me write in the next line. So you will have to make the above out.

Comment: Well, no problem I sorted it out.